# What is A, B = C in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am currently learning the basics of networking in Python and keep seeing this syntax, a variable, followed by another variable, but separated with a comma.

```
conn, address = s.accept()
```

I understand the s.accept(), I am just unsure of the variable that I am assigning the result of s.accept() to. When entering:

```
type(conn, address)
```

I am returned with a Tuple but I do not understand how the conn and address play any part in a Tuple, and was wondering if I could receive some guidance as to what this syntax means.

Thanks in advance, Ollie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`s.accept()` returns a tuple of two values : `(host, port)`.

Therefore,

```
conn, address = s.accept()
```

is (apart that accept() is called twice) the same as

```
conn, address = s.accept()[0], s.accept()[1]
```

Comment: Not quite the same, because the second version will call `s.accept()` twice.

Answer (score 0):

when receiving a tuple you can **unpack**(or "split") it into its members by using this syntax:

```
member1, member2, member3 = tuple
```

or

```
member1, member2 member3 = (member1, member2 member3)
```

in your case you are receiving a tuple of the form (connection, address), so to unpack it into two variables you write:

```
conn, address = s.accept()
```

It's equivalent to this:

```
returned_tuple = s.accept()
conn, address = returned_tuple
```